# SSRS 2008/2012 - ADDING AGGREGATION FIELDS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-2012

I'm attempting to add a field to an SSRS report based on 2 other displayed fields. 
I'm using a matrix report

Field One is a Count of Account numbers
the Second Field is an Order Amount

My Attempt

```
    New_field=(Sum(Amount))/(Count(Account))
```

What is the best way to do this in SSRS. Because one cannot have Aggregate functions in SSRS.

A second and related issue is Percent increases.  What would be the best way to generate Percent differences in a new column.

Notes:
1. The report is fueled using a SQL Stored Procedure.
2. Graphical Display vs tabular are acceptable

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply put your formula in query and give it an `ALIAS`. I've also use `CASE` statement to catch the error when `Count(Account)=0`.

```
SELECT 
      CASE WHEN Count(Account)=0 THEN (Sum(Amount))/(Count(Account)) END AS New_field
FROM TableName
```

Comment: Hrmm, Using that method I didn't get the output as expected. it simply took the count of my individual account number (obviously 1) and the Amount they spent (call it X) and did the math. X/1 = X.  My issue is that I seek to aggregate the counts and amounts, Over Months, Over some demographics etc.  It is pretty simple to aggregate the Count of Years and the revenue sums but the last field i require is the         sum of the aggregate Amounts divided by the count of the Aggregate account numbers. Does that make more sense?